# PHP - Post to Facebook Page using SDK no errors but no posts showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the tutorial here http://www.adamboother.com/blog/automatically-posting-to-a-facebook-page-using-the-facebook-sdk-v5-for-php-facebook-api/ to post to a facebook page using the PHP sdk.

I have create the app on Facebook, and I have created the Never Expire Page Access Token, which I have verified using the Access Token Debug Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

However, when I run my test code, it does NOT return any errors, but I get no posts on my page.  I get a response back from my `print_r($graphNode)` of the following

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1204777049583245_1264619360265680
        )
)
```

The code for my test post is below, can anyone explain to me WHY I am not getting any posts to show up?

```
define("FACEBOOK_APP_ID","MY APP ID");
define("FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET","MY APP SECRET");
define("FACEBOOK_APP_TOKEN","MY PAGE ACCESS TOKEN");

define("FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/socialmedia/Facebook/src/Facebook/');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/socialmedia/Facebook/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

//Post property to Facebook
$linkData = [
     'link' => 'www.yoururl.com',
     'message' => 'test message'
];
$pageAccessToken = FACEBOOK_APP_TOKEN;

try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($graphNode);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Comment: So 1204777049583245 is the id of your page? That seems to be access restricted in some way, or not published yet. Are you using the same user to view the page timeline, that granted the page token? You need to set your app live, otherwise only people with a role in the app will be able to see content created through it.

Comment: @CBroe, I'm not sure how do I check if that is the ID of my page?  I am using the same user to view the page timeline as I only have one account.  How do I set the app to live?

Comment: You set it live on the App Review tab.

Comment: @CBroe - Okay, so I've made it live and when I post I get the same response back but nothing shows when I view my timeline.  No errors, just no new posts.

Comment: @CBroe - it works.  Stupid me, I created the Page Access Token to a sub page on my site so it was posting, just not to where I was looking for it.  I'm an idiot.  Thank you for your help!